# HP WebInspect Scan Pauses

Tags: security, testing, scanning, web-inspector

I scanning my website using HP webinspect. The issue that i am facing is that after some time webinspect pauses giving Error (11004). What I can access is that when ever a page gives 404 error webinspect scan stops. I need help in this regard. Specially I would want webinspect to continue scanning by skipping the pages that it is getting error from.